# single page website translation, indexation and SEO

Tags: javascript, html, seo, translation

I have a webpage, let say `www.mypage.com/index.html`. I have a javascript function able to fill the page with my own translation of the content thanks to json dictionaries. In the end, www.mypage.com/?lang=en will display the content and fill it with the english language. www.mypage.com/?lang=fr will display the content and fill it with the french language.

For instance :

```
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        translate(getURLParameter("lang"));
    </script>
</head><body>
    <p id="content0">default content</p>
</body></html>
```

The `translate` method will transform :

```
<p id="content0">default content</p>
```

into

```
<p id="content0">translated content</p>
```

This is what I'm currently able to do. What I would like is a solution to simulate an english webpage and a distinct french webpage, without duplicate content, and optimized for SEO. I need to keep using my dictionaries as the translation is in there.

My website is hosted on an Apache 2 server if it helps.

**edit:** I thought I would necessary need to do that in php (a language I don't know very well), but thanks to the hreflang meta, I think there could be a trick to do it in  HTML+JS. Any hint ?

Thank you !

Comment: Different languages with different addresses is not considered duplicate content. You have to watch out for similar languages though, like British and american.

Comment: Hum, ok. Got it. So I can have 2 translated pages. But for now I have only one that can be translated thanks to a JS function. It's easier for maintenance, but not at all for indexation. Is there a compromise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you do something like this and do a static pre-render so the crawler gets the keywords you want. There are various ways to do this but I really like this one.

https://prerender.io/

Comment: Wow !!! This seems awesome !
Ok, I'm just lost right now about how it works, so I look into it and I come back

Comment: Ok, I have a first question. With this method, the meta tags will not be translated am I correct ? (meta description for instance). Is there a way to render the page with 2 different descriptions ?

Comment: Actually Google has a really nice guide about how pages are crawler when using something of this nature, and how the meta tag can be used.  https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Comment: Ok, I'm gathering information on the subject for 2 hours, and I'm still lost. Please help ! Let's say that mypage.com can have 4 states : mypage.com/?A=true&B=true, mypage.com/?A=true&B=false, etc. How concretely can I make these states look like 4 distinct pages for crawlers ? I'm sorry, english is not my mother language and I don't understand everything in your article...

Comment: @Tim — Don't use that horrible Google Ajax crawling thing. It's a hack to work around the problems introduced by using hashbangs but, now we have `pushState` and friends, hashbangs are obsolete.

Comment: @user1967800 — That's 4 different URLs. They are already 4 distinct pages.

Comment: hum, so for my first example, mypage.com/?lang=fr and mypage.com/?lang=en will both be referenced ? Should I make a sitemap including them ?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting he architect a solution around them, I suggested he used a rendering service to handle it all. I a just giving him a link to see how Google crawls the URLs

Comment: Ok Tim, I understand now. I thought you wanted me to use hashbangs. Anyway, I understand that the rendering service will render the page for me. Can I influence the meta with this method ? I would like to translate the meta description...

Comment: Another question about the link you sent me. Is it the same to cache mypage.com/?A=true&B=true and mypage.com/?B=true&A=true ?

Comment: Ok, I still would like to know about my last question, but for the previous one, I gave up on doing it with JS and did it with php.